# How to use ng-repeat in a grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display my array in to two columns per row, with angular directives is this possible? or do i have to write some logic in the controller.

Controller:

```
//don't know if i have to put some logic here
```

Model:

```
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'lemon']
```

View:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <div class="col">{{fruits}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm using ionic framework

Comment: with my example could you please provide a code

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use bootstrap `col` classes for this, that would place only two element on single row by splitting it into 50% and 50% as calculation of 12 cols.

**Markup**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{fruit}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @teddybear123 it should work in ionic too..only you need to include `bootstrap` js & css

Answer (score 0):

With the class names in your provided code I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap. If you want 2 columns per row, just make each column 50% width with col-md-6:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <div class="col-md-6">{{fruit}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong you want to show data in table view and every column have different data. Just create data in json format as required.

```
 $scope.stock=[{name:"shocks",qty:"4"},{name:"shoes",qty:"4"}]
```

from using  above scope you can bind it in two column by different property by simple JavaScript table property.

```
<div ng-repeat="node in stock">`{{node.name}} 
{{node.qty}}`
```

Comment: If you want to UI related changes (colspan view), you can use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to achieve the required way, though not much recommended by all

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(k,v) in fruits">
        <tr ng-if='$even'>
            <td>{{fruits[k]}}</td>
            <td>{{fruits[k+1]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/hukumi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can solve by creating an intermediate JSON array by modifying initial array.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'lemon'];
   $scope.temp = [];
   while ($scope.fruits.length) {
            $scope.temp.push($scope.fruits.splice(0, 2))
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div   ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <tbody ng-repeat="fruit in temp">
            <tr >
                <td>{{fruit[0]}} </td>
                <td>{{fruit[1]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```